# Regular Expression in column to match string in another column

Tags: regex, t-sql

Does any one know a technique, where I can use a regular expression-pattern that exists as a string in one column, to match a string in another column?

**Example**

```
Table 1:
RegExCol | ValueColumn1 | ValueColumn2
--------------------------------------
pattern1 |     foo      |    bar
pattern2 |     bar      |    foo

Table 2:
StringValue |
-------------
LongString  |
```

I want to get values from ValueColumn1 and ValueColumn2 based on which pattern that matches my LongString - ideally in a t-sql join. SSIS is also a possibility. We are running SQL SERVER Enterprise 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this will work for you. [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) command is limited, not actual RegEx

```
select a.ValueColumn1, a.ValueColumn2
from Table1 a inner join table2 b
  on b.LongString  like a.RegExCol
```

Comment: I found out that I need SQL CLR, so i need to post another question once I know a bit more about it. You will get correct answer for the effort :)